# Find a 3d equation that goes through a series of points?

Tags: functional-equations, 3d

I have a series of points in 3d space and I need to find an equation that goes through all of them. What would be the best way to do this?

Points:
(3.7, 0.45, 0.7)
(5.2, 0.8, 0.96)
(6, 1.04, 1.15)
(7.5, 1.4, 1.4)
(10, 2.1, 1.8)
(30, 16, 6.6)

Comment: Do you need a surface or a curve ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Sorry, my geometry is a bit lacking. I need a function so that I can plug in any 2 of the 3 numbers and get the remaining one.

Comment: It is probably a surface then. Can you show the point  cloud ?

Comment: What is the purpose ? (No curiosity, this information is necessary to give relevant advice.)

Comment: I need a simple, if not accurate, way to relate the mass, radius, and surface temperature of main sequence stars. My way of doing this has been to take a series of examples and try to create a 3 dimensional linear function.

Answer (score 0):

The given data points seem to be aligned on a curve. The first five are in a straight line but the sixth deviates noticeably.

For simplicity, we can admit that the relation between $M$ and $S$ is relatively linear and through the origin,

$$S\approx rM,$$ where $r=\dfrac{6.6}{30}$.

Then the $(M,R)$ relation can be approximated with a parabola which passes through the origin, of the form $$R\approx aM^2+bM.$$

We can obtain it by a Lagrangian interpolation through the origin and the points $5$ and $6$, and we get $a=\dfrac{9.7}{600},b=\dfrac{29}{600}$.

[image]